# How to force VS 2019 xunit tests to use a specific testhost.exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit

In the VS folder there are a bunch of testhost exe located. By default the testhost.exe is used. I know I can switch to x64 but the testhost targets .NET 4.0 which can get into the way when you rely on newer .NET Framework features such as e.g. long path support.
How can I switch to the newer testhosts?

[image]

Even if that works the testhost.exe for .NET 4.6.2+ has not set the flag

```
<longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
```

in the exe  manifest. I gues I would need to write a bug report to MS to address this.
See e.g. PerfView what needs to be done to add long path support: https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/issues/1304

Comment: How did you run your tests and which version of xUnit is used?

Comment: I am using xunit.runner.visualstudio v2.4.3. There I run it from the Visual Studio Test Explorer